# Generate a collection test (Mongodb)

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to fill and generate a test collection (100 documents), these are my attributes:

_id: "serial integer from 1 to 100", component: "string", specifications: ["an Array of max 3 words"], description: "string", date: "date", type: "2 possible values type1 or type2", status:"Boolean"

I started writhing a script, please can you check it and help me to complete it (type, status and date), thank you

```
for(var i=0; i < 100; i++)
    {
      var x = i;
      var varName = "component" + i;

      db.collectionName.insert(
       {
         _id: x, component: varName, specifications: [""], description: "", 
         date: "", type: "", status:"" 
       });

      for(var j=0; j < 3; j++)
       {
           db.collectionName.update({"component": varName }, 
         {$push: {"specifications":"spec"+Math.floor(Math.random()*50)}},
         false, true)
        }

       db.collectionName.update({"component": varName}, 
       {$set: {"description": "test description"+Math.floor(Math.random()*10)}})
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Also, what do you want to test? Do you want to create test data for other tests or is the creation of the data part of your test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do updates

```
for(var i=0; i < 100; i++){    
  var varName = "component" + i;
  db.collectionName.insert(
   {
     _id: i, 
     component: varName, 
 specifications: ["spec"+Math.floor(Math.random()*50),"spec"+Math.floor(Math.random()*50),"spec"+Math.floor(Math.random()*50)], 
     description:  "test description"+Math.floor(Math.random()*10), 
     date: new Date(), 
     type: i % 2 ===0  ? "type1" : "type2", 
     status: i % 2 ===0 
   });
}
```